# Cannot set property of undefined TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I want to set object with data and then pushed it to another object

```
let globalSamples = {} as any;
let sample = { } as ISamplesDetail [];
sample = [];
for (let i = 0 ; i<this.prelevementLingette.samplesDetail.length; i++)
    {
      sample [i].id= this.old.samplesDetail[i].id;
      sample [i].reference=this.old.samplesDetail[i].reference;
}
globalSamples.push(sample);
```

I got this error  `'Cannot set property 'reference' of undefined'`

How can I resolve the problem ?

Comment: use an if statement. something like  `if (!sample[i]) continue;` in order to jump to the next iteration if sample[i] is null or undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems in your code, so I've cleaned it up a bit

```
// looks like this would be a proper type..
const globalSamples: ISamplesDetail[][] = [];

// can't assign object ({}) what should be an array, so..
// value doesn't change -> const
const sample: ISamplesDetail[] = [];


// it's strange that you iterate over 'this.prelevementLingette',
// but access 'this.old'
for (let i = 0 ; i < this.prelevementLingette.samplesDetail.length; i++) {
      sample[i] = {
          id: this.old.samplesDetail[i].id,
          reference: this.old.samplesDetail[i].reference
      }
}

// can't push to an object (should be array - [])
globalSamples.push(sample);
```

It seems like the logic in your code is a bit twisted, but it's difficult to say without knowing the context

Comment: It works! What do we call this syntax ? And Why my code doesn't work. It's seems the same

Comment: what syntax exactly?